# Create an instance of a class inside the class

Tags: java, class, object

I have a class (State) in Java in which I have a method that fills an ArrayList with instances of the class (State). When I add an instance I change the variables of it but the variables of my initial class are also changed. I tried using this.variable in the constructor but it didn't work. Is there a way this won't happen?

Comment: Code. We need to see the code. You're asking us to debug in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding new instances of the class instead of this

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I create new instances and add them.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found it. The problem was that instead of using:

```
state2 = state1.clone()
```

I used:

```
state2 = state1
```